# Angular Select Box Update Multiple Parameters

Tags: angularjs, select

I'm new to angular, and struggling with updating bound values from a select box that is inside a modal which is populated based on a particular row of data that is "edited" in a table. Currently, I can click edit, the select box populates with the correct values and selected option based on the user row I "edited". My problem is I can update either the ID or the Title of my model but not both. Here is my html select:

```
    <select ng-model="user.team">
      <option ng-selected="{{x.id}} === user.team.id" ng-repeat="x in teams" ng-selected="{{x.id}} == {{user.team.id}}"  value="{{x.id}}">{{x.title}}</option>
    </select>
```

Note that if I make ng-model="user.team.id" it updates the id correctly in my list, and "user.team.title" updates the title correctly. My scope/model is defined as such and I would like to update both id and title when the option is changed:

```
    $scope.user = {
      team :{
    id: '',
    title: ''
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
<select ng-model="user.team" ng-options="x.title for x in teams track by x.id"></select>
```

`ng-model` will set the initial selection to the option that matches `user.team`

Comment: That did succeed in updating the "title" in the table correctly, however it no longer is pre selecting the proper option, it's also sending what appears to be a string "[object Object]" (not the actual object) to my rest API, I need to send the ID, this is helpful though, I'm working on it and will post back it I get it fully resolved.

Comment: Okay got it, you answer helped me get on the right track of not specifying each option as a ng-repeat. Heres what worked  <select ng-model="user.team" ng-options="x.title for x in teams track by x.id">
        </select>

Comment: ha! was just trying to edit my answer to add `track by x.id` :) my bad, forgot to add it originally.

Comment: Go ahead and edit it, I'll mark it as answered, had answered my own question, but that was cheap of me, so I deleted, edit it up ++!